# what is the meaning of 100% of 100%?

Tags: arithmetic

When we say `a% of b`, we mean `'a' parts out of the 100 parts of 'b'`.
 e.g. *1% of 200 means divide 200 in 100 equal parts and select 1 out of it, i.e. 2*

So,
what does it mean when we say **any percentage of any percentage?**
like, what is the **significance of 100% of 100%**?

Comment: divide 100% in 100 equal parts and select 100 out of it, i.e. 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100 percent. percent=per hundred. 100% is 100 per 100=100/100=1. So 100% of 100% is 100% of 1, which is 1. 50% of 50% is 50% of .5, or half of 50%, which is .25, or 25%. You convert them to their numeric representation and multiply.

For contrast, there is the (less common) [per mil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mil), which is 1/1000. 1000 per mil = 100 per cent = 1. You're really working with decimal numbers the whole time, just with units of 1/100 or 1/1000.